# How to get all words from round brackets then replace all with a html div code

Tags: javascript

```
var message = $("textarea").val();
var matches = message.match(/\((.*?)\)/);
if (matches) {
var submatch = message.replace('(' + matches[1] +')', '<div id="'+ matches[1] +'"></div>');
console.log(submatch);
```

The `message` variable is a textarea and `div` is a CSS image with a smiley that shows smiley on my chat app. When I use `"This is (smiley1) and (smiley2)"`, the sub-match variable is showing me just smiley1 and the smiley2 remain same with brackets; like `"This is smiley1 and (smiley2)"`. I can't get this DIV with `id` (smiley2) that includes brackets because `id` is without brackets, but I need brackets because this a chat message with smilies in brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String#replace` can replace via regex, which is what you're trying to do. Use the `g` flag to make it a global regex that can match more than one thing. Giving a callback function will allow you to get each match's group. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more.

```js
var message = "This is (smiley1) and (smiley2)";
var result = message.replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, function(match,p1) { return '<div id="'+p1+'"></div>'; });
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

*As a prequel, I'd like to say that @Klaycon's answer would be my preferred method for how to address the usecase.  While I like their answer for how to accomplish the task, it doesn't explain the reasoning as to why the code in the question is not working; or how it could be modified (not replaced) to get it to work.  Below is an attempt to address that.*

---

### Explanation

Without using the regex global flag (i.e. `g`), `.match()` will only pull the first matched response.  So your `matches` variable was an array of the first matched text and its capture group.  It looked something like the following (notice it does not contain anything for smiley2):

```
[ "(smiley1)", "smiley1" ]
```

One might think you could simply slap on the `g` to your regex and get all the capture groups, but JavaScript is not Perl (or another language that might allow that).  The RegEx engine is powerful, but limited.  Instead, you would have to make use of the `matchAll()` method.  However, even that is limited as it returns an iterable object and not an array.

So, once you have that object, you can create an array from it (e.g., using `Array.from`), which will contain all the matched text and capture groups.  The result would look something like:

```
[ ["(smiley1)","smiley1"],
  ["(smiley2)","smiley2"] ]
```

From there you can iterate over the matches array and use your `replace()` function.  Which brings us to the next point.  The first argument to `replace()` can be a string or a regex.  If it is a string, as you had called it, it will only do a one-time replace at the first string it comes to.  @klayton's answer uses a regex with the global 'g' modifier for repetition.  If you wanted to use the string replace, you can, you would just need to iterate over your new matches array and call it multiple times.

#### Example (array)

```js
let message = $("textarea").val();
let re      = /\((.*?)\)/g;                       // global modifier
let matches = Array.from( message.matchAll(re) ); // use matchAll 

matches.forEach(match => {
  let replace_text = `<div id="${match[1]}"></div>`
  message = message.replace(match[0], replace_text)
})

console.log(message)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
This is (smiley1) and (smiley2)
</textarea>
```

---

#### Example (iterable object)

Of course, because `matchAll()` returns an iterable object; you don't need to convert it to an array.  You could iterate over it using an appropriate  looping mechanism.  Below uses `for..of`:

```js
let message = $("textarea").val();
let re      = /\((.*?)\)/g;         // global modifier
let matches = message.matchAll(re); // use matchAll 

for (let match of matches){
  let replace_text = `<div id="${match[1]}"></div>`
  message = message.replace(match[0], replace_text)
}

console.log(message)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
This is (smiley1) and (smiley2)
</textarea>
```

---

### Final Remarks

The final point worth making is that you are replacing text with an element that has an `id`.  This is opening your page up to the possibility that you will have many elements with the same `id` value; which becomes invalid HTML, but opens you up to encountering other unforeseen issues (e.g., JavaScript event handling).  For that, I'd recommend using the class attribute instead (e.g., `class="smiley1"`).